# Android db.update not work if use db.delete first

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I have a strange problem to update a table in my database...forgive me if I can not explain well but I'm a bit confused...
The problem is this:
I created a table with values, I read this values  in my  listview..everything works for now..insert and delete values works without problem..now created a loop in a service why do I need to make a comparison between a value and a string of my database and when this comparison is true, I need to change a value in my table..

The real problem is this: my `db.update` works only if not use ... never, the command `db.delete`... if  use it, the `db.update` not work anymore ..and to make it work again, i need to make a new AVD.

how is it possible?
my `db.delete` and id is this:

```
item.getMenuInfo();
    id = getListAdapter().getItemId(info.position);

public void deleteReg(SQLiteDatabase db ,long id) 
        {
           db.delete(TabRegistry.TABLE_NAME, TabRegistry._ID + "=" + id, null);
        }
```

on activity:

```
 databaseHelper.deleteReg(db, id);
```

my db.update is this: (positions is a value of `getPositions()`,for locate a positions with a cursor(always works, even when fails db.update))

```
public void updateReg(SQLiteDatabase db,int positions, String stat)
    {
        ContentValues v = new ContentValues();
        v.put(TabRegistry.STATUS, stat);
        db.update(TabRegistry.TABLE_NAME, v, TabRegistry._ID + " = " + positions, null);
    }
```

on service:

```
   databaseHelper.updateReg(db, positions, "SUCCESS");
```

if you need more code, tell me what I add now..thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The SQLite api you are using is based off of [CRUD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Create,_read,_update_and_delete) operations (you should read this).

You are DELETE-ing the record from the database, therefore there is nothing to UPDATE when you attempt to update it. If you want to create a new record, or recreate the one you deleted then you would perform an INSERT instead of an UPDATE.

EDIT:

It also appears you are passing in position number to the update and delete. I assume that you are also using this value to place the record in your table? Is it possible that when you delete the record from the table and the database, that the other records now have an invalid position because they haven't been updated also? It's just a shot in the dark, figured I might as well ask.

Comment: true can be, how update the full table, for correct their positions?